# Calling a Javascript method from the Bokeh Google Maps wrapper (fitBounds())

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, bokeh

I have a bokeh Google maps plot with several Lat/ Lng data points, and I would like to use the fitBounds() method of the Google Maps v3 API to set the zoom level.

I have a Google Maps plot up and running, displaying on my site and showing the data points, but I need to set the zoom manually.

```py
import bokeh.io
import bokeh.models
import bokeh.plotting
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'Latitude [deg]': [18.46, 25.7, 32.3],
    'Longitude [deg]': [-66, -80.2, -64.8],
}
data_frame = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
data_source = bokeh.models.ColumnDataSource(data_frame)
mean_lat = data_frame['Latitude [deg]'].mean()
mean_lng = data_frame['Longitude [deg]'].mean()
gmap_options = bokeh.models.GMapOptions(lat=mean_lat, lng=mean_lng, zoom=10, map_type='satellite')
xy_gmap = bokeh.plotting.gmap('SuPeRSeCrEtAPIkey', gmap_options)
xy_gmap.circle(x='Longitude [deg]', y='Latitude [deg]', source=data_source, color="red")

# A callback like this? Could make the call in JavaScript after the page is loaded, and update map zoom??
# xy_gmap.fitBounds(x='Longitude [deg]', y='Latitude [deg]', source=data_source)

bokeh.io.show(xy_gmap)
```

I would like the bounds of the map to enclose all points in my dataframe, at the lowest zoom possible (as is done in Javascript by fitBounds() ). Currently, the map can only zoom to the manually set level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Bokeh 1.2, there is no built-in way to accomplish this. The only suggestion I can offer is to note that there is a global `Bokeh.index` on the JavaScript side, and in that there is `GMapPlotView` for the corresponding `GmapPlot` that you made. This view has an attribute `.map` that is the actual Google map object. You could call the `fitBounds` method on that from JavaScript code. Bokeh `GMapPlot` objects follow Google's lead wrt to plot bounds, so if they get updated, the axes, etc. should respond.

Otherwise, I can only suggest [opening a GitHub issue](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues) to discuss adding this as a new feature.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I'll look into this method and if I can make something work I'll make an issue and pull request.

Comment: Just noting if you do start a PR: the way to do this for real in the project itself would be to add a new property to `GMapPlot` and then in BokehJS apply `fitBounds` (or not) based on that property (i.e. no need to much with `Bokeh.index`)

Answer (score 0):

Starting an answer for both methods described by bigreddot (using JS Bokeh.index and Python integration)

### Bokeh.index

In the Javascript Console, you can use the following commands (should be self explanatory to get this into some JS code)

```
> var gmapPlotView;
> for (var property in Bokeh.index) { if (Bokeh.index[property].constructor.name == 'GMapPlotView') {gmapPlotView = Bokeh.index[property];} }    // Get the correct object, in the case that you have multiple plots, but only one map plot
> var bounds = gmapPlotView.map.getBounds();                  // To start from existing bounds
> var bounds = google.maps.LatLngBounds();                    // To start with fresh bounds
> var place = new google.maps.LatLng(45.5983128 ,8.9172776);  // Coordinates of place to put bounds, repeat for all points
> bounds.extend(place);                                       // Add each place to the bounds object
> gmapPlotView.map.fitBounds(bounds);                         // Set the maps new bounds
```

Note that the Bokeh google maps implementation does not plot your data on the Google Maps data layer, but on a bokeh canvas above the map (that is why there is a lag when panning the map between map tiles and your graphs).

### Python Integration

In process....